# Find element with xpath not working- Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am testing a website in order to learn how to use Selenium in C#. I am blocked from finding the login form elements because the form input element doesn't have any identifiers and the xpath isn't working in my code.

I included a [photo of the inspect element code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIWRa.png) that I see when inspecting the login form element in question. My code is as follows.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting; 
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace SeleniumTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.website.com");
            driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Login")).Click();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='divLogin']/div[1]/div[1]/div/input")).SendKeys("Username");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("Password")).SendKeys("Password");
            driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Login")).Click();
        }
    }
}
```

The xpath that I have included for the password is a placeholder of course, but it should look similar to the username one.

Upon copying the xpath using the chrome 'copy > xpath' feature, I get this - //*[@id="divLogin"]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIWRa.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIWRa.png)/div/input. That would be fine, except it doesn't work (also I have to change the " around divLogin to ' in order to get the program to work, not sure if that is part of the problem).

I have looked for existing answers for hours now and can't find anything.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: When you say this `Find element with xpath not working-` I am left out with 100 of gusses, what is the error stack trace?

Comment: Can you share the link of the website? Second, what error you get when you run your code?

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @cruisepandey A more accurate title would have been 'Can't find element with XPath', my bad

Comment: @QualityMatters yeah it's lifeinfoapp.com

Comment: @DebanjanB it's either share the screenshot or copy the code from the inspect element code I see, and that sounds like a mess. No offense, but I don't think screenshotting the element html with the element in question was a bad idea.

Comment: @ShawnWerber in my network, login is restricted for this site.

Comment: @QualityMatters Sorry, thought I put the error in the original post. It leaves me with this - no such element: Unable to locate element

Comment: @ShawnWerber The easiest way to know the locator is use selenium IDE. In your browser, add selenium IDE plugin. Then record your use case. And see how IDE is generating the locator. Most of the time, it helps you to find that the element is inside frame/shadow root etc. Second, you can inspect element from dev tools of any browser. Third, use selectorHub plugin. Fourth, there are multiple other plugins also available to find locators. Fifth, search how to create xpath, there are plethora of information available. This is how you can easily solve your basic problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to improve your element locator and use of wait for element to be used before interacting with them. The below code is able to input username and password and click on the login button.

```
String url = "http://www.website.com";
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.ClassName("login"))).Click();
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("username"))).SendKeys("your username");
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("password"))).SendKeys("your password");
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("signin-submit2"))).Click();
Thread.Sleep(4000);-> This is for viewing the page before quitting
driver.Quit();
```

**Imports:**

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
```

**How to use Explicit wait:**

Go to `"NuGet package manager`" and install `DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers` and then you will be able to use Explicit wait.

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here you can write the xpath for the input box relative to Username label. This will be the robust and stable xpath. Also make sure before entering the value this input box is loaded in the webpage. You can try to put some wait before entering the value.

```
//label[contains(text(),'Username')]/following::input
```